# I keep getting "Resource temporarily unavailable" when building tidesdk with "scons debug=1"?

Tags: tidesdk

Has anyone experienced this and might have a work around:

g++ -arch i386 -o build/osx/runtime/libtideutils.dylib -m32 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -lstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -install_name libtideutils.dylib -dynamiclib build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/app_manifest.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/application.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/boot_utils.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/data_utils.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/environment_utils.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/file_utils.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/platform_utils.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/url_utils.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/poco/KDigestEngine.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/poco/KMD5Engine.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/osx/boot_utils_osx.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/osx/file_utils_osx.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/osx/osx_utilscons: *** [build/osx/runtime/libtideutils.dylib] Resource temporarily unavailable
s.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/osx/platform_utils_osx.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/posix/file_utils_posix.os build/osx/objs/libtideutils/utils/posix/posix_utils.os -Lbuild/osx -Lthirdparty-osx-x86-v2/boost/lib -Lthirdparty-osx-x86-v2/poco/lib -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -lPocoZip -lPocoData -lPocoSQLite -framework Foundation -framework IOKit -framework Cocoa -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreServices
scons: building terminated because of errors.

Building with latest scons and current "develop" branch of tidesdk on 10.8.2. It was working before, but all of a sudden it has now started giving me the above error everytime.

Answer (score 1):

We recommend that you build from TideSDK master. As the 'develop' name implies, this is the development branch that is not stable nor supported for users.

TideSDK is complex software and this branch is utilized by the SDK's developers that generally work in c++ and python. Significant and substantial changes are occurring in the software. If you are interested in contributing to the development of the SDK, please drop by #tidesdk on freenode.

Comment: I've actually tried to send emails, but always get a rejected message when requesting to contribute. Will hop on freenode.

Comment: I lead the project and have not had any such requests. Please connect on irc on #tidesdk to discuss your interest in contributing. You can inform me where you have send your messages at this time.

Comment: Yes, I know you lead the project, I have actually tried sending you an email on your personal email that is listed on github. Also I have sent an email to help@coastalforge.com, but got a return to sender. I'll try to connect with you on freenode now.